# Probabilities of ranking positions based on predicted scores

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, linear, ranks

I have a list of students from different classes, so far I have  used a linear regression to create predicted future test scores based on multiple criteria such as attendance, previous test scores etc.

I would now like to use these predicted scores to work out the probability of each student finishing 1st, 2nd, 3rd in their class etc. One concern I have is that all the classes are different sizes.

I am very new to this, so any advice on the most efficient way to work out probabilities based on predicted scores would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can associate a distribution of scores with each predicted value, you could try simulation within each class.